# Calling a super template class method without knowing the template type in C++

Tags: c++, templates

I have a base class that uses template, and it has a few methods that are not dependent on the template type, but when I use the pointer `Base* a` instead of the derived class the compiler complains because there is no type specified. I know in java this is possible but not sure if it is possible in C++. Here a simple example:

```
template <typename T>
class Base {
public:
    Base(const T& t) : _t(t) {}
    virtual ~Base() { }

    void doSomething() { std::cout << "Hello world/n"; }

    virtual T getVal() const { return _t; }

private:
    T _t;
};

class DerivedA : public virtual Base<std::string>
{
public:
    DerivedA(const std::string& path) : Base<std::string>(path) {}
    virtual ~DerivedA() {}
};

class DerivedB : public virtual Base<int>
{
public:
    DerivedB(int value) : Base<int>(value) {}
    virtual ~DerivedB() {}
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    DerivedA d("hello world\n");
    Base* basePtr = &d; // ERROR: Use of class template 'Base' requires template arguments
    basePtr->doSomething();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you have functions which do not depend on any template arguments in their signature, like the `doSomething` function, then you could create a non-template "real" base-class that the templated `Base` class inherits from.

Comment: You can't do this. `Base<std::string>` and `Base<int>` are different specializations, and so they are distinct types. you cannot cast an apple into a car...

Comment: dont confuse java generics with c++ templates, those are two very different concepts

Comment: The suggestions to use a concrete (non-template) base class are generally correct, but it's worth checking - _why_ do you want a base class pointer? What are you using it for?

Answer (score 3):

Simply create another base class which is not a template:

```
class ReallyBase {
public:
    virtual ~ReallyBase() = default;
    void doSomething() { std::cout << "Hello world\n"; }
};

template <typename T>
class Base : public ReallyBase {
public:
    Base(const T& t) : _t(t) {}
    virtual const T& getVal() const { return _t; }    
private:
    T _t;
};
```

Comment: I suspect `ReallyBase::doSomething` should still be public here, and `ReallyBase` probably deserves a virtual dtor too.

Comment: @Useless: Thank you for not living up to your name.

Answer (score 0):

Generics in java are something completely different than templates in C++. Generics are based on type-erasure while with templates each instantiation is a seperate type completely unrelated to a different instantiation.

Ie in Java an `ArrayList<Integer>` is basically the same thing as a `ArrayList<Boolean>`. With templates on the other hand, `Base<int>` has no relation to `Base<std::string>` (other than being two types resulting from the same template) and hence your derived classes actually do **not** share a common base class.

To solve your problem you could write a (non-template) base class that declares the common interface of all your derived classes.

Answer (score 0):

Let's **1<sup>st</sup>** talk about a simple solution to your problem, writing a derivation function:

```
template<typename T>
Base<T>* make_base(Base<T>* param) {
    return param;
}
```

You can use this as follows:

```
DerivedA d("hello world\n");
auto basePtr = make_base(&d);

basePtr->doSomething();
```

This solution can be further improved as in [**this example**](https://ideone.com/3kr0VZ) but since I don't think it's the best solution I'll not clutter the answer with it but leave such optimization for your perusal.

But **2<sup>nd</sup>** let's talk about improving your design. You'll notice that any of the standard containers create a `using value_type =`... thereby storing the template types that they are passed. This is important for *this exact situation*! If you publicly add `using value_type = T` to your `Base` template class you'll circumvent the problem you're having all together, without the need for a `make_base` you'll be able to do:

```
Base<decltype(d)::value_type>* basePtr = &d;
```

---

An important follow up concept here is that `DerivedA` and `DerivedB` do *not* have the same base class. Thus you can never do something like this

```
auto basePtr = make_base(&d);
basePtr = new DerivedB({});
```