# Simpler Method for Getting the Base Class

Tags: c++, inheritance, metaprogramming, base-class, template-classes

OK so I was cooking up an [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52517511/2642059) which has more detail (and a better alternative.) But I realized I'd made a couple template functions which had a lot of redudancy. Given:

```
template<typename T>
struct Parent {};

struct Child : Parent<int> {};
```

I wrote the following template functions for getting the appropriate `Parent` pointer:

```
namespace details {
    template<typename T>
    Parent<T>* make_parent(Parent<T>* param) { return param; }
}

template<typename T>
auto make_parent(T& param) -> decltype(details::make_parent(&param)) { return details::make_parent(&param); }
```

There seems to be a lot of repetition in there. But I can't figure out how to make it cleaner. Can I combine this into a single function without it looking like a nightmare?

**EDIT:**

My intention is that I can do:

```
Child foo;
auto bar = make_parent(foo);
```

(As opposed to the easier version in the other answer, where I pass a pointer.)

Comment: FWIW you can get rid of `-> decltype(details::make_parent(&param))` in the second function as long as you have C++14 or higher

Comment: @user463035818 Arg, thank you for the comment about my other answer. That's what I get for not copy pasting code :( Now, what are you saying about this question. I don't see the problem.

Comment: @user463035818 Ugh I see it now. Seriously in my code I had this all right. Somehow I just typed it from memory and everything went wrong.

Comment: why do you need the `details` ? Just let `make_parent` take a `Base<T>` directly

Comment: @user463035818 I'll edit the question to clarify....

Comment: You know, I don't think there is a way to do this without at lease *some* repetition.

Comment: Did you intend for it to only be callable with non-const object?

Comment: @StoryTeller Honestly I hadn't thought about it. I mean it would be *nice* if that would work too, but, yeah. I just hadn't thought about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of this can be simplified to

```
template<typename T>
Parent<T>* get_parent_ptr(Parent<T>& param) { return &param; }
```

This will give you the pointer to the `Parent` part of anything derived from `Parent`

If you want to be able to handle `const` objects as well, and prevent getting a pointer to a temporary, unfortunately you will have to add a little more by adding

```
template<typename T>
const Parent<T>* get_parent_ptr(const Parent<T>& param) { return &param; }

template<typename T>
Parent<T>* get_parent_ptr(Parent<T>&& param) = delete; // if you don't care about getting a pointer to a rvalue you can remove this
```

You can see all of this working with this [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f70e9aebd4c351d7):

```
int main()
{
    Child c;
    auto cp = get_parent_ptr(c);
    const Child cc;
    auto ccp = get_parent_ptr(cc);
    //auto error = get_parent_ptr(Child{});
}
```

If you uncomment the `error` line you will get and error that you are trying to use a deleted function.

Comment: Yeah, I thought so too. But now it won't bind to non-const arguments. And if you add *that* overload, it's again repetitive. Not to mention one needs to add a deleted r-value overload... So yeah... repetition.

Comment: @StoryTeller Good point.  I've at least updated the answer with that.

Comment: Good catch on the rvalue reference I hadn't even thought of that.